# Problems with recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to solve recursions problems in Java but im stuck with this one. I'm gonna let the problem here and what i've done. Thanks for the help :D

A new type of virus has been discovered and a company has asked us to program a formula that will allow us to find out the population increase of the virus at a certain time. Initially, at time 0 (h), we have 32 viruses and every hour the number of viruses doubles. Additionally, a fixed number of viruses (num) is added every hour.

a) Perform a recursive function that calculates the total number of viruses given for an hour and a fixed number for a given virus.

b) Calculate the number of viruses we will have at hours 0, 1 and 2 with a fixed number of 10.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE:

```
public static void main (String [] Args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int h, v, f, result;
    f = 10;
    v = 32;
    System.out.println("Hours: ");
    h = in.nextInt();
   result =  TotalVirus (h, v, f);
    System.out.println("Total : " + result);
}

public static int TotalVirus (int h, int v, int f) {
    int counter = 1, result;

    if ( counter == h) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
      counter = counter + 1;
      v = v + 32 + f;
      result = TotalVirus(h,v,f);  

    }
    return result;

}
```

}

I don't really know what to write on the if statement to end the recursion.

Comment: Where do you define `counter`?

Comment: you have a mix of portuguese and english variables names, please fix it so people here can understand. @QBrute `counter` is `contador`

Comment: I just fixed it sorry, i've done it in spanish that's why it was mixed

Comment: Isn't counter set to zero each time you call the recursive method totalVirus?  Method names should start with a lower case character.

Comment: True, i set the counter to 1 now but i still lost with the if statement to finish the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int h, v, f, result;
        f = 10;
        v = 32;
        System.out.println("Hours: ");
        h = in.nextInt();
        result = TotalVirus(h, v, f);
        System.out.println("Total : " + result);
    }

    public static int TotalVirus(int h, int v, int f) {
        if (h == 0) {
            return v;
        }
        return TotalVirus(h - 1, 2 * v + f, f);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Hours: 
0
Total : 32
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Hours: 
1
Total : 74
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Hours: 
2
Total : 158
```

Comment: This code doesn't double the number of viruses each passing by hour.

Comment: SomeDude - The solution was mainly to help @Exos where/how to put `if` condition for termination. He/she is capable for the calculation part and he/she can adjust it as required.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a tail-recursive function like below:

```
public static int totalVirus (int h, int v, int f) {

    if ( h == 0 ) {
      return v;
    } 
    return totalVirus( h-1, 2*v + f, f );


}
```

So you start with an hour lets say `h = 2`, and then decrement it in each call. While decrementing you add `2*v + f` because every hour the viruses double and a fixed amount is also added.
When the hour reaches `0` you just return the existing amount of viruses.

Comment: Thanks! Now i see it, i was lost in the return statement but its obvious now. How easy it looks when u see it done haha :)